# Type inferences for a method, with generics and class inheritance

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, c#-4.0, type-inference

I have a class hierarchy that looks like this:

```
class Base<TElement>
{
    public TElement Element { get; set; }
}

class Concrete : Base<string>
{
}
```

I'd like to write a method that accepts `Base` subclasses:

```
public TConcrete DoSomething<TConcrete, TElement>()
    where TConcrete : Base<TElement>
{
}
```

Is there any way to define DoSomething, without having to define `TElement`?

The ideal solution would be if the compiler could figure `TElement` automatically, so the calling code would look like this:

```
var item = DoSomething<Concrete>();
```

I'm using C# 4.0.

Comment: `TConcrete` and `TElement` types are not related to return or argument type?

Comment: TConcrete is the return type, I've edited my question

Comment: it looks like you're trying to have something like [higher-kinded types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kind_(type_theory)) in c#, which is not supported by the language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is impossible for the following reasons:

1. As of C# 4, type inference is "all or nothing" - the compiler cannot infer some generic arguments but not others.
2. As of C# 4, it isn't possible to specify generic "wildcards", such as  `where TConcrete : Base<???>`.

Here are a few workarounds.

**Non-generic base type**: Create a base class or interface type that is *not* generic. This is a common pattern; e.g. `IEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable`.

---

**Covariant interface**: With C# 4 generic interface covariance, you can create a type-safe solution that doesn't require cluttering your types with "ugly" non-generic members:

```
public interface IBase<out TElement>
{
    TElement Element { get; }
}

class Base<TElement> : IBase<TElement>
{
    public TElement Element { get; set; }
}

class Concrete : Base<string>  {  }
```

And then:

```
// Won't work with value types.
public TConcrete DoSomething<TConcrete>()
    where TConcrete : IBase<object> { }
```

And call it like:

```
var item = DoSomething<Concrete>();
```

Comment: Your last suggestion (Covariant Interface) solves my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you make `Base` inherit a non-generic class or implement a non-generic interface, you could constrain the method to that type instead.

Otherwise, no.  Had that been possible, the `TConcrete.Element` property inside your method would have no type.
What would happen if you write

```
public TConcrete DoSomething<TConcrete>() where TConcrete : Base<>   //Illegal!
{
    TConcrete c = ...;
    var b = c.Element;    //What type is that variable?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `DoSomething` doesn't know (or care) what `TElement` is, you might want to look into creating a parent class without the type parameter:

```
class Base
{
}

class Base<TElement> : Base
{
    public TElement Element { get; set; }
}
```

Then, your `DoSomething` method would operate on class Base.

If `DoSomething` needs to know the type parameter, then no, there is no way to do what you want & you will need to supply it.